# If the interior is the set without the boundary why is the boundary not the set without the interior?

Tags: general-topology

I have formal proofs for both (one being true and one being false), but fundamentally have no idea why this to be the case. Diagrams have failed me, and I would like to gain some intuition.

Comment: It is for closed sets, the problem is with nonclosed sets because the bounday can be outside of the set.

Comment: It's hard to _draw_ an open set since you pretty much have to draw the boundary. What does your intuition tell you about an open disk?

Comment: On your comment asking about a way to think of subtraction of sets: Think of disqualification or deletion: Delete the members of $A$ that belong to $B$ and you have $A$  \  $B.$... BTW even professional mathematicians often say "$A$ minus $B $ " for $A$ \ $B$.

Comment: If you replace the word *boundary* with *border* (the set intersected with its boundary) then both are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition (see, for example, the first sentence here: [wikipidea, interior of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))), the **interior** of a set X is a subset of X:

$$\text{interior}(X) \subseteq X.$$

For example, when considering the real numbers, the interior of the closed interval $[-1,1]$ is the open interval $(0,1)$. Now, if you remove the $0$ from that interval:

$$X:=[-1,1]\backslash \{0\} = [-1,0) \cup (0,1]$$

the interior of $X$ is

$$\text{interior}(X) = (-1,1) \backslash \{0\} = (-1,0) \cup (0,1).$$

The point $0$, which lies in the middle of our $X$, does not become an interior point.

OTOH, the **boundary** of a set X is something that can be empty, or a subset of X or partially in X and partially not in X or a superset of X. Note that in the definition here ([wikipedia, boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology))) does not say that a point of the boundary must belong to the set.

As examples, if we consider the real numbers and start again with $X=[-1,1]$, then

$$\text{boundary}(X)=\{-1,1\}$$

The boundary is just two numbers, $-1$ and $1$; in this case $\text{boundary}(X) \subset X$.
If we consider the open interval $Y=(-1,1)$ and the half open interval $Z=[-1,1)$, then they all have the same boundary as X:

$$\text{boundary}(Y)=\text{boundary}(Y)=\{-1,1\},$$

so we have $Y \cap \text{boundary}(Y) = \emptyset$ and $Z$ contains exactly one of its two boundary points.

Your questions suggests to me that you think that a set is equal to its interior plus the boundary:

$$X=\text{interior}(X) \cup \text{boundary}(X) \leftarrow\text{ WRONG! }$$

That is generally wrong, as can be seen by the recent examples of $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=[-1,1)$.

Instead, that union is called the closure of $X$, and it is a superset of $X$:

$$ X \subseteq \text{closure}(X):=\text{interior}(X) \cup \text{boundary}(X)$$

And because the definitons of interior and boundary are not symmetric, the boundary isn't (generally) the set without the interior, they can be points in the boundary that do not belong to the original set.

Comment: Is there an intuitive way to think of subtracting sets? I think my issue arises from things such as $A\setminus \bar{A} = \emptyset $, whereas in normal subtraction one would expect some negative.

Comment: You get intuition by usage. With sets, 'negative numbers' don't make sense, so the empty set is the 'smallest' you can get. The main non-intuitive thing is that if I tell you that $A$ contains 3 elements and $B$ contains 2 elements, and aks you how many elements $A\backslash B$ contains, the answer can be anything from 3 to 1, unlike 'normal' arithmetic with numbers. But it's the same with addition/union as well. Again, intuition comes from usage.